# Get subdirectories with Symfony 2 Finder component

Tags: php, symfony, filesystems, php-5.6

I am using the SF2 [Finder Component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/finder.html) to access a directory and grab the subdirectories inside it.

This is my code:

```
$finder = new Finder();
$dirs = $finder->directories()->in($this->getParameter('crmpicco.image_upload_path'));
```

The `image_upload_path` contains 3 directories: `/small`, `/medium` and `/large`

When I dump out the `dirs` attribute of what `Finder` returns I get:

```
  -dirs: array:1 [▼
    0 => "/var/www/crmpicco/20150805093500/app/files/import_images"
  ]
```

How can I modify this call to access `/small`, `/medium` and `/large` ?

Comment: `dirs` is a private property, how are you accessing it? Can you please post the code that dump the results?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggested to use a wildcard but after some tests, it seems that the result is the same with or without a wildcard.

With `getIterator()` I was able to lists all the children of a directory. On my filesystem there is a `/var/www/` containing a `html` directory.

```
$finder = new \Symfony\Component\Finder\Finder();
$dirs = $finder->directories()->in('/var/www')->depth('< 1');
foreach($dirs->getIterator() as $iterator) {
    print_r($iterator);
}
```

This code return this:

```
Symfony\Component\Finder\SplFileInfo Object
(
    [relativePath:Symfony\Component\Finder\SplFileInfo:private] => 
    [relativePathname:Symfony\Component\Finder\SplFileInfo:private] => html
    [pathName:SplFileInfo:private] => /var/www/html
    [fileName:SplFileInfo:private] => html
)
```

So I think the problem is due to the fact that you use a private property of `Finder` instead of calling `getIterator()`:

> When I dump out the `dirs` attribute of what `Finder` returns I get: